# angular ng-change for div

Tags: java, angularjs

I want to enable save button only when any of the field within div is modified. My div contains many text fields, select and check boxes. I am looking for something (possibly a directive) which will look through all scope variables(ng-models) within the entire div and enable the save button when changed.

I understood that only textarea,text and select fields can have ng-change directive. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

To start with, i have created a directive which should trigger automatically when fields under div is changed. However this directive never been triggered. I have mentioned this directive on HTML div tag.

```
.directive('enableSave', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not bind all the ngModels to fields of an object, create a backup copy of that object initially, and if the object state is different from the state of the backup copy (using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals), then enable the button?

Comment: can you post some working example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `$scope.$watch` for this. Put a watch on the model that is being passed into the directive and enable the save button when a change is triggered, for example:

```
.directive('enableSave', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch('modeltowatch', function(newvalue,oldvalue){
          // Enable save button
        })
    }
  }
});
```

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-dirty to check if the form has been modified or not. 
Examples can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)